# Discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}$ for square-free $d$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Claim:** The discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to

$$\begin{align*} d,&\quad\text{if } d\equiv 1\text{ mod }4\\
 4d,&\quad\text{if } d\not\equiv 1\text{ mod }4
\end{align*}$$

**What I have done so far:**
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}$ has the $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $(1,\sqrt{d})=:(e_1,e_2)$. The discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is defined by

$$disc_{\mathbb{Q}}(1,\sqrt{d}):=det(Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}}(e_i\cdot e_j))$$

Calculating $e_i\cdot e_j$ gives $e_1\cdot e_1= 1$, $e_1\cdot e_2=e_2\cdot e_1=\sqrt{d}$, $e_2\cdot e_2= d$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and define

$$m_x:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}),\quad q\longmapsto xq.$$

Calculating the representing matrizes $[m_x]$ for $x\in\{1,\sqrt{d},d\}$ gives

$$(1,\sqrt{d})=(1,\sqrt{d})\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow [m_1]=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(1)\big/\mathbb{Q}}(1)=2,$$

$$(\sqrt{d},d)=(1,\sqrt{d})\begin{pmatrix}
0 & d\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow [m_\sqrt{d}]=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & d\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt{d})=0,$$

$$(d,d\sqrt{d})=(1,\sqrt{d})\begin{pmatrix}
d & 0\\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow [m_d]=\begin{pmatrix}
d & 0\\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}}(d)=2d.$$

Now one can calculate the discriminant

$$disc_{\mathbb{Q}}(1,\sqrt{d})=det(Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\big/\mathbb{Q}}(e_i\cdot e_j))=det(\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2d
\end{pmatrix})=4d.$$

**Questions:**
Now if $d\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$, it holds $4d\equiv 0\text{ mod }4$? Even if $d\not\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$, doesn't there follow $4d\equiv 0\text{ mod }4$ as well?  Why is the discriminant equal to $d$ or $4d$?

Comment: Ok, the definition I am using requires, that the elements of the basis are also elements of the ring of integers. There one has to take $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ for example as second basis vector. I will give this a try.

Comment: So as Stefan also mentioned one has to take the basis $(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})$ for $d\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$, since it must also be an integral basis. I give the results on the traces with respect to this basis: $Tr_{\mathbb{Q}\big/\mathbb{Q}}(1)=2$, $Tr_{\mathbb{Q}\big/\mathbb{Q}}(\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})=1$, $Tr_{\mathbb{Q}\big/\mathbb{Q}}(\frac{(1+d)+2\sqrt{d}}{4})=\frac{d+1}{2}$. Therefore the discriminant is $det(\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&\frac{d+1}{2}\end{pmatrix})=d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discriminant of a number field extension is defined as the discriminant of the ring of integers with respect to the integral basis. This number is always same regardless of which integral basis you use. On the other side the discriminant of a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ or in general of any extension depends on the basis.

So in your case you need to prove that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is:

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}],&\quad\text{if } d \not\equiv 1\text{ mod }4\\
 \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right],&\quad\text{if } d\equiv 1\text{ mod }4
\end{align*}$$

To prove this let $\alpha \in O_k \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, the ring of integers. Then we have that $\alpha = \frac{a+b\sqrt{d}}{c}$ and we might assume that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. Then it's minimal polynomial is $x^2 - \frac{2a}{c}x + \frac{a^2 - db^2}{c^2} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

If $\gcd(a,b) = m$, then the free coefficient gives us that $m \mid b$, as $d$ can be assumed to be squarefree, which is impossible. So $m=1$ and $c\mid 2$, so we consider two cases $c=1,2$. $c=1$ will yield the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, so we need to check when $c=2$ is possible. If this is the case then we have that $4 \mid a^2 - db^2$ and so $m$ is a quadratic residue modulo $4$ and as it's squarefree we must have $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

This gives us that an integral basis $\mathbb{Q}$ is:

$$\begin{align*} \{1,\sqrt d\},&\quad\text{if }d \not\equiv 1\text{ mod }4\\
 \left \{1, \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right \},&\quad\text{if } d\equiv 1\text{ mod }4
\end{align*}$$

Now you should be able to compute the discriminant in each case.

Comment: @ Stefan4024. I noticed this in the meanwhile and made a comment on this, see above. Still, it is nice to have your more detailed answer! Thank you for this! By the way, I just finished the calculations and got the result. :)

Comment: @user408858 As a remark I don't know why you are using the trace to calculate the discriminant. In general discriminant is defined as the square of the determinant of all the conjugates of the basis. In quadratic case we have that:

$$\text{disc}(1,\sqrt d) = \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & \sqrt{d} \\
    1 & -\sqrt{d}
    \end{vmatrix}^2$$

While the one using the trace is more of an alternative way of calculating it.