# Squarefree discriminant and ring of integer

Tags: number-theory

The goal of this exercice is to use discriminant to compute the ring of integers.
I have a question about this exercice: specially point 3.

1. Let $ A$ be a PID with field of fractions $K$. Let $ L/K$ be a finite, separable field extension, and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Let $ \mathcal{B}$ be a $K$-basis of $L$ contained in $B$. Prove that if $ \operatorname{disc} \mathcal{B} $ is square free, then $\mathcal{B} $ is an $A$-basis of $B$
2. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] $ for $ \alpha$ a root of $ X^3 + X + 1 $. Show that
   $ \mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$
3. Show that if $ K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) $ for some $d $ squarefree, then
   $ \mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] $ if $ d=2,3 \mod 4 $ and $ \mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2} ] $ if $ d \equiv 1 \mod 4$

I did it in this way:

1. We have that $ \mathcal{B} = \{ b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n \} $ is a $K$-basis of $L$ contained in $ B$, where $ n  =[ L : K] $, then since all element in the basis are also contined in $B$ we can express them in a $A$-basis of $B$, say $ \mathcal{A} = \{ a_1,\ldots, a_n \} $, then we get that $ b_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{i,j} a_j   $, and thus we get a matrix $ M := (\lambda_{i,j})_{i,j} $, let be $  \operatorname{Hom}_{K}(L, \overline{K}) = \{ \sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_n \} $ then we have that
   $ \operatorname{disc}(b_1, \ldots, b_n) = \left( \det ( \sigma_i(b_j) ) \right)^2 $
   clearly we have that
   $ \sigma_i(b_j) = \sigma_i \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_{j,k} a_k \right)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_{j,k} \sigma_{i}(a_k) $
   thus defining $ C := (( \sigma_{i}(b_j) ))_{i,j} $ and $ D := (( \sigma_{i}(v_j) ))_{i,j} $, we have that $ C = DM^T$ thus we get that
   $ ( \det C)^2 = ( \det D M^T)^2 = (\det D)^2 ( \det M)^2 $
   and thus
   $\operatorname{disc}(b_1, \ldots, b_n) =  ( \det M)^2 \operatorname{disc}(a_1, \ldots, a_n) $.
   Now since the $\operatorname{disc}(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ is supposed to be square free, we would have that $ \det M \in A^{\times} $ and the results follow.
2. It's okay
3. For this point i will separate the case, i have that the minimal polynomial of $ \sqrt{d} $ is given by $x^2-d$ thus it has two root $\sqrt{d} $ and$-\sqrt{d}$, let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be the two embedding, such that $\sigma_1(\sqrt{d})=\sqrt{d} $ and $ \sigma_2(\sqrt{d}) = - \sqrt{d} $, thus we have in the case that $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$ that
   $ \operatorname{disc}(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}) = \det \begin{pmatrix}
    \sigma_1(1)& \sigma_1(\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})  \\
    \sigma_2(1)& \sigma_2(\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})   
   \end{pmatrix}^2 =  \det \begin{pmatrix}
    1& \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2} \\
    1& \frac{1-\sqrt{d}}{2}   
   \end{pmatrix}^2 = d $
   that is, it is squarefree and thus $(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})$ it is a $ \mathbb{Z}$-basis of $ \mathcal{O}_K $.
   In the case when $ d=2,3 \mod 4$ we get that
   $ \operatorname{disc}(1,\sqrt{d})=4d$
   it is not squarefree, so i don't know how to conclude.

Comment: It is no problem that $4d$ is not square free. Obviously $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$ is an integral basis in this case - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770930/discriminant-of-mathbbq-sqrtd-big-mathbbq-for-square-free-d?rq=1) here.

Comment: I agree with you that is not a problem that is not a square free, in the previous chapter (without the knowleged of the discriminant) there was an exercice were we are asked to prove that ring of integer of quadratic field extension was that one. Using the fact that the trace and the norm field are integers iff the element is in the ring of integer. So i was thinking that we are able to deduce the result only with the discriminant information also when $ d \equiv 2,3 \mod 4 $. Since it the same exercice in two different chapter.

Comment: I got it, if we suppose that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] $ is not the ring of integer then $ \operatorname{disc}(1,\sqrt{d}) = [\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]]^2 \cdot \operatorname{disc}(\mathcal{O}_K)=4d$, but then since $d$ is square free the only possibility is that $[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]]=2$ and $\operatorname{disc} \mathcal{O}_K = d$ but this is a contradiction to the Stickelberger criterion since $d \equiv 2,3 \mod 4$